# Order Form Line Pricing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

I have a simple product order form where I'm calculating line totals. The price for a particular product changes based on the quantity being ordered.

So, for 10 or more of "product" the price is $895. For less than 10 the price is $925.

I've got the form calculating my line total when a quantity is entered, but I'm stuck on the conditional statement required for the separate pricing schemes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<tr>
  <td>G Plus Mariner Sport 36V 250W</td>
  <td>$1,299</td>
  <td>$925</td>
  <td>$895</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td><input class="qty" id="qtybox" type="text" /></td>
  <td>$<span id="linetotal"></span></td>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#qtybox').change(function(){
    $('#linetotal').text($(this).val() * 925);
 });    
});
```

Comment: you can use http://jsfiddle.net for demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if` statement to put **condition** like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/xjAaR/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#qtybox').change(function(){
    qty = $(this).val()
    if(qty < 10)
        $('#linetotal').text(qty * 925);
    else
       $('#linetotal').text(qty * 895);
 });    
});
```

Comment: Javascript's type coercion should take care of that... `alert('10' * 2); //=> 20`. It would be a problem if it were `+`...

Comment: Thanks @elclanrs, I removed the parseInt

Comment: Thanks a lot Adil & elclanrs! I really appreciate the help.